# Unexpected nonstandard direction

Tags: css, css-transitions, gradient, linear-gradients

I am working on a projekt where I need to check Sonar analyzis due to clean code and quality.

I face the following issue and have unfortunately no clue what is the problem.

I have the following CSS file:

```
/* progress bar IE */
progress {
  color: #507311;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 14px;
}

/* progress bar FF */
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgba(75, 108, 16, 1) 37%, rgba(134, 181, 29, 1) 69%);
}

/* progress bar Chrome */
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: transparent;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(75, 108, 16, 1) 37%, rgba(134, 181, 29, 1) 69%);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

At -moz-progress-bar I got the following Sonar issue:

**Unexpected nonstandard direction**

I have tried the followings:

```
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(75, 108, 16, 1) 37%, rgba(134, 181, 29, 1) 69%);
}
```

and

```
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgba(75, 108, 16, 1) 37%, rgba(134, 181, 29, 1) 69%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(75, 108, 16, 1) 37%, rgba(134, 181, 29, 1) 69%);
}
```

They did not help.

Has anybody a clue what is wrong?

https://rules.sonarsource.com/css/RSPEC-4651

Comment: Look up the syntax to the direction in a linear-gradient. This reference should help - you are using incorrect values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient()

Comment: Thanks a lot. In this case I do jot see why "to bottom" does not work...

Comment: I agree. The final example is not 'illegal' AFAIK and is accepted by Firefox when given to it in vanilla CSS. Sorry not to have solved this. But as to bottom is the default does it work for you if you just leave it out?

Comment: @a-haworth yeah, it worked that way - when I left the position side out. Strange, but at least it is OK now. Thanks!